# Sort functionality for fullcalendar event objects

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Does [fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) support sorting of [clientEvents](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/clientEvents/) objects, I need them for notification functionality which will show the latest of the events?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the last event just select the last elements of the array:

```
var events = $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'clientEvents');
var lastEvent = events[events.length -1];
```